# React router not working, even with historyApiFallback set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have following problem: React router works in no way. Whether I reload page or link to route, it doesn't work. On Reload I get a white page and on a link, Nothing happens apart from URL change. Strangely I could get it to show the right component when I changed the source file (App.js) where the routes are defined. I am using WebpackDevServer so I though issue was there but I have tried all solutions found online and nothing works. Help?!?

devserver.js :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

var server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
})

server.listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

App.js:

```
@observer
export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.stores = this.props.stores
    this.history = this.props.history
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.authenticate()
}

authenticate(e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault()
    this.props.stores.appState.authenticate()
}

render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <Router history={this.history}>
                <Provider {...this.stores}>
                    <div className="wrapper">
                        {/*<DevTools />*/}

                        <TopBar />

                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/"
                            render={(props) => <LazyRoute {...props} component={import('./Home')}/>}
                        />

                        <Route
                            path="library"
                            render={(props) => <LazyRoute {...props} component={import('./Library')}/>}
                        />

                    </div>
                </Provider>
            </Router>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
}
}
```